# Find value and remove first level key from multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

This is my array.

I am trying to locate a specific date and remove that entire key from the array (both corresponding start_time and end_time.

```
    $c = array
    // Search all end_times        
    $remove = '2012-06-24 17:00:59';
```

> array(2) {
>
> > [**0**]=>
> >     array(2) {
> >
> > > [**0**]=>
> > > array(2) {
> > >
> > > > ["ID"]=> string(2) "15"
> > > > ["start_time"]=> string(19) "2012-06-24 08:00:00"
> > >
> > > }
> > >       [**1**]=>
> > > array(2) {
> > >
> > > > ["ID"]=> string(2) "15"
> > > > ["end_time"]=> string(19) "2012-06-24 17:00:59"
> > >
> > > }
> >
> > }
> >
> > [**1**]=>
> >     array(2) {
> >
> > > [**0**]=>
> > >       array(2) {
> > >
> > > > ["ID"]=> string(2) "28"
> > > > ["start_time"]=> string(19) "2012-07-26 18:00:00"
> > >
> > > }
> > >
> > > [**1**]=>
> > >       array(2) {
> > >
> > > > ["ID"]=> string(2) "28"
> > > > ["end_time"]=> string(19) "2012-07-26 22:00:59"
> > >
> > > }
> >
> > }
>
> }

This is the code I have so far.  It works only when targeting the first start_time, or the second end_time, which suggests to me that the count is getting lost somewhere.  I'm pretty new to PHP so I have very little clue as to whats next.

```
   // recursive array search, look for value, remove key
   for ($i = 0, $count = count($c); $i < $count; $i++) {
       if ($c[$i][$i]['end_time'] == $remove) {
           unset($c[$i]);
   } 
   }
```

Would appreciate any help on this!
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($c as $k=>$v) {
   foreach ($v as $line) {
      $times = array('start_time', 'end_time');
      foreach ($times as $time) {
         if ($line[$time] == $remove) {
            unset($c[$k]);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Should do what you're looking for, if I understand correctly.

EDIT: Basically what it does is take each member of the original array and search each member of that parent array for the remove time. If it finds it, it removes the entire "tree."

Comment: Added another curly brace at the end, but doesn't appear to work sorry

Comment: If you don't mind, please upvote this answer as well. Much appreciated.

Comment: What about if I wanted to reverse it? e.g. if ($line[$time] != $keep) { -- this doesn't work as I expected returns array(0) { }

Comment: It would be `if ($line[$time] != $remove` Not sure what you're trying to do

Comment: I just realized it needed to be the other way around.  if I change == to != it breaks.  I appreciate your quick followup!

Comment: What you have provided works if I want to remove a date.  However if I wanted to keep a date and remove all the rest it doesn't appear to be as simple as changing == to != ..  I'm creating a drop down box so when user selects a date, only the dates in the array should be there.